# Using = as suffix to variables in f-strings

Tags: python-3.x, f-string

Consider the following code :

```
data='a,b,c'  
print(f'{data=}')
```

The output for this is `data='a,b,c'`
What I do understand is that any variable put inside curly braces in the f-string will be
replaced with its value. so print(f'{data}') outputs `a,b,c` which makes sense. But what exactly is happening here `{data=}`?